# Table created but not visible in database while using hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, oracle10g

[application wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baHwU.png)

[SQL command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJaY.png) ---showing account locked because of repeated wrong passwords, which is working fine in application wizard.

Everything seems to be right even in log info it is showing the table is created and data is inserted on the same, but I am unable to see the table and data in database.Can anybody suggest the possible reason.

**Database** : Oracle 10g

### Log Info

```
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:30 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:30 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE]
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=system, password=****}
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:32 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Hibernate: drop table UserDetails cascade constraints
Hibernate: create table UserDetails (userid number(10,0) not null, userName varchar2(255 char), primary key (userid))
Jun 12, 2016 8:38:33 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@1c3146bc'
Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (userName, userid) values (?, ?)
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.username">system</property>
<property name="connection.password">diwakar</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

<mapping class="com.diwakar.dto.UserDetails"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### UserDetails.java

```
package com.diwakar.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    private int userid;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


}
```

### HibernateTest.java

```
package com.diwakar;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.diwakar.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserid(1);
        user.setUserName("Diwakar");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();


    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you connecting as SYSTEM? Which schema did you create the table in - hopefully not in the SYSTEM schema? If you did then that's a bad idea, but are you sure you're connected to the same database?

Comment: Actually my schema is diwakar previously, but if i provide username diwakar. then it is giving error stating that username/password is incorrect. although is wrong practice but just for try purpose that's why I just provided system and it runs. but I am able to acess the schema with password provided in xml file.i again tried by using diwakar schema now i ma getting error stating usename/password is incorrect.

Comment: <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.username">diwakar</property>
<property name="connection.password">india</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>

Comment: But you were able to connect to that XE instance as `diwakar` and create the table as that user? With password `india` - with the same case? If you log in as `system` you need to qualify the table name with the schema it belongs to. But that's a hack, figure out why you can't connect as yourself.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?` run this SQL to find where this table is actually created

Comment: From application wizard i am able to access database schema
username : diwakar
pwd : india
but when i am trying same thing from sql command line i am getting message like username/password is wrong.
not exactly sure how come it is possible..?
though i resolve the issue by creating new schema user1 and everything working smooth.
but still very much confusing how come is it possible that it is working through application express wizard but not through sql command line.

Comment: also added screen shots.
1st one == able to access the schema diwakar with password india.
2nd one == unable to access.

Comment: @UUID 
Is there any solution for problem mentioned above?, also attatched the screenshot for the same.